# Will an S4 boot and run without a volume button?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, buttons

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 with a dented/stuck volume button (causing any attempt to boot to end at the screen that asks whether I really want to install a custom OS because the smartphone perceives *volume down* as pressed).

I am planning to dispose of that device after getting (read: copying and wiping) some data from its internal memory.

As replacing the button costs a lot (both at the official and at other repair shops), I am considering just removing the button.

**Will the smartphone work (and keep working for an hour or so) without the volume button?** I am wondering whether anything in the system will notice the button is missing and refuse to boot. Also, an employee at one of the smartphone repair shops I went to claimed humidity would enter the smartphone through the opening, and anyway, the repair shops outright refused to remove the button without replacing it<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Presumably because then, I'd pay less. I will remove the button myself, if I find no-one to do it for money, though.

Comment: The thing is, the Odin confirmation screen should only show up when *both* HOME and VOL- are held. Probably your HOME key needs to be taken care of too.

Comment: Were it just the volume button, it would've been just a matter of removing some screw, tinker with the button and reassemble. The Home button is far harder to reach.

Comment: @AndyYan: The *Home* key doesn't show any external signs of damage and feels like it could be pressed normally. Also, from the way the issue first occurred (while holding the device in the hand and using it), I consider it likely that *Home* is undamaged. Still, if we assume *Home* is just as stuck, what would happen if only *Home* were pressed while booting?

Comment: @AndyYan: I can now confirm the *Home* button is undamaged. I managed to get the S4 to boot again, by tweaking the volume button with a knife, as [described in another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77411/48610). This provided me with an opportunity to get all of my data back from the device. I will leave this question open, though, as it may still be worthwhile to know for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The phone can boot and run without volume button. You just have to make sure that neither volume down nor volume up button is pressed after removing the external button otherwise you may enter into recovery/Odin mode or into installing custom ROM mode. So remove the external button and boot up the phone as usual.